Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'plugins')
I'm trying use chartjs-plugin-colorschemes plugin, but in your documentation says that I need install and import plugin, I use these commands:
yarn add chart.js chartjs-plugin-colorschemes react-chartjs-2

After I import
import 'chartjs-plugin-colorschemes';

on my code
'use client';

import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';

import DashboardLayout from '@/components/layout';
import {Database} from '@/types_db';
import {Session, User} from '@supabase/supabase-js';
import {redirect} from 'next/navigation';
import Card from "@/components/card/Card";
import React from "react";
import {Button, IconButton, Option, Select} from "@material-tailwind/react";
import MainDashboardTable from "@/components/dashboard/main/cards/MainDashboardTable";
import tableDataUserReports from "@/variables/tableDataUserReports";
import {ArrowLeft} from "phosphor-react";
import {CategoryScale, Colors} from 'chart.js';
import {Bar} from "react-chartjs-2";
import json from "@/variables/okta_monthly.json";
import {parserDataset} from "@/utils/utils";
import 'chartjs-plugin-colorschemes';

// ...

Chart.register(CategoryScale);
Chart.register(Colors);

// ...

const options = {
        plugins: {colors: {
                forceOverride: true,
                enabled: true,
            },
            colorschemes: {
                scheme: 'brewer.Paired14p'
            },
            subtitle: {
                display: true,
                text: "Number of events",
                position: 'left'
            },
            legend: {
                display: true,
                position: 'right',
            },
        },
        scales:{
            x: {
                type: 'category',
                stacked: true,
                labels: graphicData.labelsPeople,
                ticks: {
                    maxRotation: 90,
                    minRotation: 90
                }
            },
            x2: {
                type: 'category',
                stacked: true,
                labels: graphicData.labelsX2,
            },
            y: {
                stacked: true,
            },
        }
    };

// .... 

But always return this error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'plugins')


I said earlier I can't use plugin chartjs-plugin-colorschemes on my project in nextjs and in the docs haven't enought data about this issue.

If you look at the line 1040 of chartjs-plugin-colorschemes.js(reported as thew source of the error in the error stack you posted as an image) you'll see that it is Chart.defaults.global.plugins.colorschemes = ....; trying to console.log Chart.default.global we get undefined; downgrading the version of chart.js, we'll see the last version that had Chart.default.global was 2.9.4. Here's a relevant link to the source code about that change (the TODO-version 3 text).

In conclusion, the plugin you are trying to use, not updated for 5 years, is not compatible with newer (post v3) versions of chart.js, although it might not be very difficult to update it yourself to make it compatible. In any case, its valuable assets are, numerous color definitions in the colorschemes directory are easily salvageble.
